# Is it necessary to watch "The X-Files" Movie before Season 6?

Tags: continuity, the-x-files

I have watched seasons 1-5 of the X-Files.  In the first episode of season 6, the intro shows scenes from the end of season 5 and what I guess is "The X-Files" movie.

Do I need to watch the movie before season 6 for it to make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't want to give away the reasons why as it would include spoilers, but yes you should watch the movie before watching Season 6 as there is continuity from the movie into Season 6.

Hopefully this is not too much of a spoiler but I'll block it out just in case you want to avoid it all together.

> The movie shows a characteristic of the black oil that explains where greys come from, and the main "creature" from the movie shows up in the first episode of Season 6.

Comment: It's a minor point, but they had also closed the X-Files at the end of season 5. The film explains how they got reopened before season 6.

Comment: Minor point but a good one :)